# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, view, adapter

I am using custom Adapter class to work with RecyclerView, here is my code:

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    List<NatureItem> mItems;

    public CardAdapter() {
        super();
        mItems = new ArrayList<NatureItem>();

        NatureItem nature = new NatureItem();

        nature.setName("The Great Barrier Reef");
        nature.setThumbnail(R.drawable.great_barrier_reef);
        mItems.add(nature);

        nature = new NatureItem();
        nature.setName("Grand Canyon");
        nature.setThumbnail(R.drawable.grand_canyon);
        mItems.add(nature);

    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_card_item, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        NatureItem nature = mItems.get(i);
        viewHolder.tvNature.setText(nature.getName());
        viewHolder.imgThumbnail.setImageResource(nature.getThumbnail());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public ImageView imgThumbnail;
        public TextView tvNature;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imgThumbnail = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail);
            tvNature = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nature);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the complete **Log:**

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at com.github.florent37.materialviewpager.sample.CardAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(CardAdapter.java:53)
            at com.github.florent37.materialviewpager.sample.CardAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(CardAdapter.java:18)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:4385)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3700)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3609)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1859)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1311)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1274)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:525)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2118)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:2415)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14063)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1594)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14063)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14063)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14063)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:907)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14063)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14063)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14063)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14063)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14063)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14063)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1996)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1817)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1114)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4520)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreograp
```

CartAdapter **Line number: 53**

```
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
```

CartAdapter **Line number: 18**

```
   public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {
```

What could be the reason ? Why i am facing this issue.. Is there something else where i have to make change ?

**Solution** provided by `@Abhishek` and `@Shvet`, it resolved the exception but still getting something like this, RecyclerView over MaterialViewPager by default (which is not ok)

**EDITED AGAIN:**

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        // mAdapter = new CardAdapter();
        mAdapter = new RecyclerViewMaterialAdapter(new CardAdapter());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        MaterialViewPagerHelper.registerRecyclerView(getActivity(), mRecyclerView, null);

        mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                })
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: What does your XML file look like?

Comment: @BidhanA i posted xml too

Comment: Do you have all the dependencies in your build.gradle file?

Comment: yes.. i am all the dependencies

Comment: Please try this.... Replace public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {      to      public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

Comment: check your dependencies

Comment: change  `View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())` to `View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity().getApplicationcontext())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried you code in a sample app. It took me a while to figure out that below two lines in `recycler_view_card_item.xml` is causing the issue.

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
```

If I am correct (I cannot be sure though since you haven't posted that part of the code), you haven't declared `activity_horizontal_margin` in your default `dimens.xml` **(res\values\dimens.xml)**. You need to declare this in default dimens to fix the issue, something like this

**dimens.xml**

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">64dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Hope that helps:)

**Edit :** You need to add place holder in fragment to push down Recycler view. Refer usage guide of `MaterialViewPager` library - https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager. This has been mentioned there.

Change your **fragment_recyclerview_advance.xml** to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/material_view_pager_placeholder" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit 2:** To fix the scrolling issue remove the place holder I suggested in previous edit. But wrap your RecyclerView adpater with `RecyclerViewMaterialAdapter` provided by the library

```
 mAdapter = new RecyclerViewMaterialAdapter(new CardAdapter());
 mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Full code:

**fragment_recyclerview_advance.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**RecyclerViewFragment.java**

```
public class RecyclerViewFragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

    public static RecyclerViewFragment newInstance() {
        return new RecyclerViewFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recyclerview_advance, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mAdapter = new RecyclerViewMaterialAdapter(new CardAdapter());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        MaterialViewPagerHelper.registerRecyclerView(getActivity(), mRecyclerView, null);
    }
```

Comment: That should give Error during compilation not at runtime.

Comment: Nope..The values are present in some other directory(ex values-w820dp) ..so it won't give error during compile time..But during run time it tries to access default values and app will be crashed if it is not found.

Comment: That could be the case, but how do you know it exits in values-w820 or etc ? he havn't posted that.

Comment: he is using the sample app from [this](https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager) library. I noticed same mistake (declared `activity_horizontal_margin` in  values-w820 but not in default values) in their sample app. I can't be sure if he has done same mistake though. But it is worth a try.

Comment: Probably. As per the logs `Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class <unknown>` exception is in unknown class. I doubt gradle missed something or Fragment inflation causing the issue.

Comment: Hmm. The thing is that I tried his code in a sample app. It was giving the same exception. But then I declared `activity_horizontal_margin` in default values and the app was working just fine.

Comment: hmm could be that problem. lets see.

Comment: thank you so much, i have divided two stream awards between two deserving developers you and @shvet i hope you both would like that

Comment: Hi Abhishek may i know why my Recyclerview hiding ViewPager, i posted screen above

Comment: thank you so much buddy :) superb solution, sorry i tried it today was enjoying weekend, i hope you too.. your solution helped me to achieve what i wanted to get, but still facing issue when scrolling to top, i have posted screenshots above please check, and one more thing i would like to award you with a bounty for your incredible efforts, so i am starting that now

Comment: I am little busy now. Will look into the issue in the night.

Comment: @Oreo Check `Edit 2` in my answer. It fixes the scrolling issue.

Comment: It's fine if u are using custom adapter. Just wrap it around `RecyclerViewMaterialAdapter`. Like  `mAdapter = new RecyclerViewMaterialAdapter(new CardAdapter());`. Here `CardAdapter` is your custom adapter. Try n let me know.

Comment: tons of thanks :) you are the master, i have replaced this line mAdapter = new CardAdapter(); with mAdapter = new RecyclerViewMaterialAdapter(new CardAdapter()); but still i need a small help of yours, now i am using GridLayoutManager instead of LinearLayoutManager (again showing item over viewpager) check EDITED AGAIN section above i posted my code

Comment: Great. and I guess to use the GridLayoutManager you need to pass spanCount to RecyclerViewMaterialAdapter.  so `mAdapter = new RecyclerViewMaterialAdapter(new CardAdapter(), 2);` . can you try this?

Comment: Good morning.Little busy right now, Will look into the issue when I am free:)

Comment: Hello brother, when i do Scroll to bottom and then to top getting blank space of 2 cols (like we spanned by 2) How do I resolve this issue ? ...thank you

Comment: Can you send the link to your latest sample project so that I look into the issue?

Comment: i noticed that, whenever i am  using youtube's thumb url getting this issue even i do have only 60 records, but whenever i am thumb url's which i have uploaded to my server not facing any issue... what could be the reason ?

Comment: I don't think I can answer that question without looking into the code. Can you post the code where you are loading the youtube thumb url and screenshots of blank spaces?

Answer (score 1):

After Checking your Code I got Solution. It is As @Abhisheck answered. It is problem of dimen declaration. Add `<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">64dp</dimen>` in to `dimen.xml` file. Also you have to change your Style from `ActionBar` to `NoActionBar`. Check Below Edits.

**values/dimens.xml**

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="cardMarginHorizontal">10dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="cardMarginVertical">8dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">64dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**style.xml**

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Also You need to upgrade your Dependencies.

**build.gradle(sample)**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'

    //compile ('com.github.florent37:materialviewpager:1.0.1@aar'){
    //    transitive=true
    //}

    compile project(':materialviewpager')
}
```

**build.gradle(Project)**

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'
        classpath "com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.1"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Let me know if anything is wrong.

Comment: thanks brother i have given you bounty and ticked your answer as useful, and accepted @Abhishek's answer as he found that issue first, but for me you both are at same level - those like to help others :)

Comment: found any solution, why RecyclerView hiding ViewPager ?